# simpleSFTP cannot check if file exists

Tags: grails, sftp

My app is grails 2.4.5 and Java OpenJDK 1.8.

I am using the Grails simpleSFTP plugin (https://github.com/perrydevx/simple-sftp) to upload/download and delete files from an SFTP server, but I also want to be able to check if a file exists on the SFTP server, but it looks like simpleSFTP cannot do this.

I could rename the file, and then name it back again, catching exceptions if the file doesn't exist, but it's a bit inelegant to do it this way.

Is there a similar library that can help here?

TIA.

Comment: Why not just get a file/directory listing to see if the file exists?

Comment: Seems like you could pretty easily extend this plugin to expose the `sftp.ls` command, which already exists.

Comment: @Griff  Yes, that's what I'm asking. How do I do that?!

Comment: @Daniel  do you think you could give an example of how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

It has been a while since I worked with grails 2, so anyone more familiar with it feel free to edit, correct, etc.

The *best* way to do this would be to either fork your own copy of the plugin and update it to have the functionality you want.  A more practical approach might be to simply add the SimpleSftpService.groovy class into an appropriate package in your project.  In grails 5 (and 4, but I don't remember about earlier versions) a local copy of the same class takes precedence.

Once you have your own copy of SimpleSftpService, add a method along these lines:

```
def listFiles(String dirName) {
    connect { ChannelSftp sftp ->
        sftp.ls dirName
    }
}
```

Explore the API here https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html to see the methods available to you.

Comment: Perfect!  Does exactly what it says on the tin. Thank you very much.